# Joining multiple strings in Grails

Tags: string, grails, concatenation

I am new to Grails and beyond a little bit of PHP have little development experience. I'm looking for the best way to combine multiple strings I've been successful using the + operator as follows but am not sure if this is the most effective way.  I tried sorting it out using StringBuilder but could not get it to work. Any examples showing that would also be appreciated.

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName

    static constraints = {
       some constriants...
    }

    String toString() { return lastName + ',' + lastName + ' ' + middlename }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
return "$lastName,$lastName $middleName"
```

Comment: In fact you don't even need the `return` because in Groovy there is an implicit return of the last expression evaluated.

Comment: You can also surround your fields in curly brackets.  This is needed if you have text that bumps up to the back end of any referenced field.  So "$lastNameIsTheGreatest" will not work as it looks for that field, but "${lastNameIsTheGreatest}" will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Groovy language is very flexible for this improvements, I explain this:

In Java you have:

```
private String field;

public String toString(){
  return "new String" + field;
}
```

In Groovy as you know the 'public' word is optional but also the keyword 'return' is optional too and we can use a GString implementing the $ operand

In Groovy you have:

```
String toString(){
  "new String $field" // cool, uh
}
```

Is a lil' of syntactic sugar...

Regards